# Convolution operation without conditional loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, convolution

I am writing a convolution operation for a filter and a signal. The accumulation operation holds true only for the condition "j - k" is not < 0. Is there a way to remove this condition and try to split the loops to avoid the conditional clause.

```
for (i = 0; i < RBs ; i++)                // Over Resource Blocks
{
    for (j = 0; j < (IFFT_Len + Fil_Len -1); j++)        ​// Over Output Length
    {
        acc = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < Fil_Len; k++)   // over conv operation
        {
            if (j-k >= 0)
            {
                acc += Filter[k + (i * fil_data)] * IFFT[j - k + (i * ifft_data)];
            }
        }
        x[j] = acc;
    }
    UFMC_sig += x;
}
```

Comment: if you change the inner loop to `for(k = 0; k <= j; k++)` you don't need the `if(j-k >= 0 )` check.

Comment: Thanks Adrian however "k" has to be less than "Filter_len" as well. So " && k < Fil_len" would be another condition in the for loop. Would that again reduce performance ?

Comment: Always measure performance. Do not rely on conjectures.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I meant in the instance when k is < j but larger than its actual limit "Fil_len", wouldnt that be exceeding the predefined limit and itļl throw error, something like "array index out of range" or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes - I guess you saw my comment just before I deleted it (I saw it was wrong).

Comment: Couldn't you declare another variable before the loop such as `upper_bound = j > Fil_Len ? Fil_Len : j;` then make a `for` loop such as `for(k = 0; k < upper_bound; k++)` if you want to reduce the number condition computation ?

Comment: Yes, thank you something like that will work. I am actually running this on a processor and looking for ideas where somehow there wouldnt be any conditional operations to avoid extra cycles. But if nothing works, this seems the best choice. Thanks :)

Comment: why do you want to remove the conditional statement in the first place?  anyway, this should be equivalent functionally and a bit better performance-wise `for(k = 0; k <= j && k < Fil_Len; k++)`

Comment: @Serge I am running this on a vector processor and lesser the no. of conditional statements better the performance. I was thinking if the loop could be somehow broken into two for loops to handle negative indices (when k is greater than j) and not reduce perf as well.